# 'manifestOutputDirectory' with gradle-plugin 3.3.0 not returning result

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Trying to get manifest output directory, with below code in app build.gradle

```
def manifestOutDir = manifestOutputDirectory
```

But instead of returning directory path, when I run build and print it, it shows this string

```
property(interface org.gradle.api.file.Directory, transform(property(interface org.gradle.api.file.Directory,
...
```

I am using gradle-plugin-3.3.0 with 
Android Studio 3.3

Is it not working with gradle-android-plugin-3.3.0 or removed? Anything else that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

This post [https://stackoverflow.com/a/46037817/4181904] indicates that this feature is broken.

Essentially, instead of accessing the outputFile directly from the gradle API, the recommendation is to access the directory containing the file instead. The snippet below demonstrates this with a manifest file, but can be applied to other outputFiles as well.

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        output.processManifest.doLast {

            String manifestPath = "$manifestOutputDirectory/AndroidManifest.xml"
            def manifestContent = file(manifestPath).getText()

            // Manipulate the file as needed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This line `String manifestPath = "$manifestOutputDirectory/AndroidManifest.xml"` gives output error like so  `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Android\MyApp\app\property(interface org.gradle.api.file.Directory, transform(property(interface org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultProjectLayout$FixedDirectory, C:\Android\MyApp\app\build))))\AndroidManifest.xml (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)`

Comment: It actually concates weired string starting from 'property(interface.....' to the app path.

Answer (score 1):

In high gradle version maybe above 3.3 , the Library's `AndroidManifest.xml` is moved from package `.../merged_manifests` to `.../library_manifest`. So if you use this code to get the path will not work. More detail you could see [Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0](//developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#manifestOutputFile)

```
 def manifestPath = manifestOutputDirectory.asFile.get()
```

**NOW, You should just use this to get the `AndroidManifest.xml`:**

```
 def manifest = manifestOutputFile.asFile.get()
```

Have fun

Comment: Could not get unknown property 'manifestOutputFile' for task , not working anymore